# retrieve the statistics like api usage, response times into a file in wso2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

i'm collecting API statistics using below link.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+REST+Client

Instead of accessing in console is there anyway i can retrieve the statistics like api usage, response times into a file?

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: Do you want to collect raw data or the summarized data?

Comment: I want summarized data for each metric. I need to store in a file where it is easily readable and send it to logstash for monitoring/alerting purpose.

Comment: In API Manager, stats are published to WSO2 DAS and it will summarize the data. Summarized data will be written to the database (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Publishing+Events+Using+Apache+Spark). In your case it is not possible to write to a file directly. You can check available publishing methods (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Creating+Alerts).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can I configure google analytics and get api usage, response time etc statistics? Can I fetch that data from google analytics using google api's(if any) and store it in some other format?

Comment: This guide (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Integrating+with+Google+Analytics) explains how you can configure google analytics with API Manager. But I am not sure whether you can get all the required information from this integration.